# R Studio plot window has become blurry

Tags: plot, rstudio

Only recently the plots displayed on the R Studio plot window have become blurry (~antialiased). Output through png() is fine, only texts are antialiased but axis and plots display sharply. But all content displayed on R Studio's plot window has become blurry which is an annoyance.

I am using R Studio 1.1453 on W10 and didn't have this problem before.

Is this some R Studio configuration issue? perhaps some W10 update modified the way RStudio plot window works? can it be fixed to make it behave as it used to?.

Thanks

[issue comparison RStudio vs png()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clrXJ.png)